# How can you do anything useful without mutable state?

Tags: functional-programming, state

I've been reading a lot of stuff about functional programming lately, and I can understand most of it, but the one thing I just can't wrap my head around is stateless coding.  It seems to me that simplifying programming by removing mutable state is like "simplifying" a car by removing the dashboard: the finished product may be simpler, but good luck making it interact with end-users.

Just about every user application I can think of involves state as a core concept.  If you write a document (or a SO post), the state changes with every new input.  Or if you play a video game, there are tons of state variables, beginning with the positions of all the characters, who tend to move around constantly.  How can you possibly do anything useful without keeping track of changing values?

Every time I find something that discusses this issue, it's written in really technical functional-ese that assumes a heavy FP background that I don't have.  Does anyone know a way to explain this to someone with a good, solid understanding of imperative coding but who's a complete n00b on the functional side?

EDIT:  A bunch of the replies so far seem to be trying to convince me of the advantages of immutable values.  I get that part.  It makes perfect sense.  What I don't understand is how you can keep track of values that have to change, and change constantly, without mutable variables.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844536/advantages-of-stateless-programming

Comment: My personal humble opinion is that it's like strength and money. The law of diminishing returns apply. If you are fairly strong, there may be little incentive to get slightly stronger but it doesn't hurt to work at it (and some people do with a passion). 
The same applies to global mutable state. It is my personal preference to accept that as my coding skill progresses it is good to limit the amount of global mutable state in my code. It may never be perfect but it is good to work towards minimizing global mutable state.

Comment: Like with money, a point will be reached were investing more time into it, is no longer highly useful and other priorities will rise to the top. 
If for instance, you reach the greatest amount of strength possible (per my metaphor) it may not serve any useful purpose and could even become a burden. But it is good still to strive towards that possibly unattainable goal and invest moderate resources into it.

Comment: Briefly, in FP, functions never modify state. Eventually they'll return something that _replaces_ the current state.  But the state is never modified (mutated) in-place.

Comment: There are ways to get statefulness without mutation (using the stack from what I understand), but this question is in a sense beside the point (even though it's a great one). Hard to talk about succinctly, but here's a post which hopefully answers your question https://medium.com/@jbmilgrom/why-functional-and-object-oriented-programming-are-often-juxtaposed-1017699112d7. The TLDR is that the semantics of even a stateful functional program are immutable, however communication b/w runs of the program function are handled.

Comment: Also, if you are worried about efficiency of immutable data structures see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure. Can find a nice explanation here (https://augustl.com/blog/2019/you_have_to_know_about_persistent_data_structures/) with reference to Clojure, which relies heavily on this implementation strategy

Comment: I don't think every application has a state as a core concept. The application has a series of events that happened as a core concept. The events can be "folded' to get the current state. The series of events is the source of truth, the state is just a point in time.

Answer (score 186, accepted):

> Or if you play a video game, there are
>   tons of state variables, beginning
>   with the positions of all the
>   characters, who tend to move around
>   constantly. How can you possibly do
>   anything useful without keeping track
>   of changing values?

If you're interested, [here's](http://prog21.dadgum.com/23.html) a series of articles which describe game programming with Erlang.

You probably won't like this answer, but you won't *get* functional program until you use it. I can post code samples and say "Here, don't you *see*" -- but if you don't understand the syntax and underlying principles, then your eyes just glaze over. From your point of view, it looks as if I'm doing the same thing as an imperative language, but just setting up all kinds of boundaries to purposefully make programming more difficult. My point of view, you're just experiencing the [Blub paradox](http://www.paulgraham.com/avg.html).

I was skeptical at first, but I jumped on the functional programming train a few years ago and fell in love with it. The trick with functional programming is being able to recognize patterns, particular variable assignments, and move the imperative state to the stack. A for-loop, for example, becomes recursion:

```
// Imperative
let printTo x =
    for a in 1 .. x do
        printfn "%i" a

// Recursive
let printTo x =
    let rec loop a = if a <= x then printfn "%i" a; loop (a + 1)
    loop 1
```

Its not very pretty, but we got the same effect with no mutation. Of course, wherever possible, we like avoid looping altogether and just abstract it away:

```
// Preferred
let printTo x = seq { 1 .. x } |> Seq.iter (fun a -> printfn "%i" a)
```

The Seq.iter method will enumerate through the collection and invoke the anonymous function for each item. Very handy :)

I know, printing numbers isn't exactly impressive. However, we can use the same approach with games: hold all state in the stack and create a new object with our changes in the recursive call. In this way, each frame is a stateless snapshot of the game, where each frame simply creates a brand new object with the desired changes of whatever stateless objects needs updating. The pseudocode for this might be:

```
// imperative version
pacman = new pacman(0, 0)
while true
    if key = UP then pacman.y++
    elif key = DOWN then pacman.y--
    elif key = LEFT then pacman.x--
    elif key = UP then pacman.x++
    render(pacman)

// functional version
let rec loop pacman =
    render(pacman)
    let x, y = switch(key)
        case LEFT: pacman.x - 1, pacman.y
        case RIGHT: pacman.x + 1, pacman.y
        case UP: pacman.x, pacman.y - 1
        case DOWN: pacman.x, pacman.y + 1
    loop(new pacman(x, y))
```

The imperative and functional versions are identical, but the functional version clearly uses no mutable state. The functional code keeps all state is held on the stack -- the nice thing about this approach is that, if something goes wrong, debugging is easy, all you need is a stack trace.

This scales up to any number of objects in the game, because all objects (or collections of related objects) can be rendered in their own thread.

> Just about every user application I
>   can think of involves state as a core
>   concept.

In functional languages, rather than mutating the state of objects, we simply return a new object with the changes we want. Its more efficient than it sounds. Data structures, for example, are very easy to represent as immutable data structures. Stacks, for example, are notoriously easy to implement:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    static class Stack
    {
        public static Stack<T> Cons<T>(T hd, Stack<T> tl) { return new Stack<T>(hd, tl); }
        public static Stack<T> Append<T>(Stack<T> x, Stack<T> y)
        {
            return x == null ? y : Cons(x.Head, Append(x.Tail, y));
        }
        public static void Iter<T>(Stack<T> x, Action<T> f) { if (x != null) { f(x.Head); Iter(x.Tail, f); } }
    }

    class Stack<T>
    {
        public readonly T Head;
        public readonly Stack<T> Tail;
        public Stack(T hd, Stack<T> tl)
        {
            this.Head = hd;
            this.Tail = tl;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stack<int> x = Stack.Cons(1, Stack.Cons(2, Stack.Cons(3, Stack.Cons(4, null))));
            Stack<int> y = Stack.Cons(5, Stack.Cons(6, Stack.Cons(7, Stack.Cons(8, null))));
            Stack<int> z = Stack.Append(x, y);
            Stack.Iter(z, a => Console.WriteLine(a));
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

The code above constructs two immutable lists, appends them together to make a new list, and appends the results. No mutable state is used anywhere in the application. It looks a little bulky, but that's only because C# is a verbose language. Here's the equivalent program in F#:

```
type 'a stack =
    | Cons of 'a * 'a stack
    | Nil

let rec append x y =
    match x with
    | Cons(hd, tl) -> Cons(hd, append tl y)
    | Nil -> y

let rec iter f = function
    | Cons(hd, tl) -> f(hd); iter f tl
    | Nil -> ()

let x = Cons(1, Cons(2, Cons(3, Cons(4, Nil))))
let y = Cons(5, Cons(6, Cons(7, Cons(8, Nil))))
let z = append x y
iter (fun a -> printfn "%i" a) z
```

No mutable necessary to create and manipulate lists. Nearly all data structures can be easily converted into their functional equivalents. I wrote a page [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Advanced_Data_Structures) which provides immutable implementations of stacks, queues, leftist heaps, red-black trees, lazy lists. Not a single snippet of code contains any mutable state. To "mutate" a tree, I create a brand new one with new node I want -- this is very efficient because I don't need to make a copy of every node in the tree, I can reuse the old ones in my new tree.

Using a more significant example, I also wrote [this SQL parser](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Lexing_and_Parsing) which is totally stateless (or at least *my* code is stateless, I don't know whether the underlying lexing library is stateless).

Stateless programming is just as expressive and powerful as stateful programming, it just requires a little practice to train yourself to start thinking statelessly. Of course, "stateless programming when possible, stateful programming where necessary" seems to be the motto of most impure functional languages. There's no harm in falling back on mutables when the functional approach just isn't as clean or efficient.

Comment: I like the Pacman example.  But that could solve one problem only to raise another:  What if something else holds a reference to the existing Pacman object?  Then it won't get garbage-collected and replaced; instead you end up with two copies of the object, one of which is invalid.  How do you handle this problem?

Comment: Obviously you need create a new "something else" with the new Pacman object ;) Of course, if we take that route too far, we end up recreating the object graph for our entire world everytime something changes. A better approach is described here (http://prog21.dadgum.com/26.html): rather than having objects update themselves and all of their dependencies, its much easier to have them pass messages about their state to an event loop which handles all of the updating. This makes it much easier to decide what objects in the graph needs updating, and which ones don't.

Comment: @Juliet, I have one doubt - in my totally imperative mindset, recursion must end at some point, otherwise you'll eventually produce a stack overflow.  In the recursive pacman example, how is the stack kept at bay - is the object implicitly popped at the beginning of the function?

Comment: @BlueStrat - good question ... if it's a "tail call" ... ie the recursive call is the last thing in the function ... then the system doesn't need to generate a new stack frame ... it can just reuse the previous one.  This is a common optimization for functional programming languages. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call

Comment: @reteptilian - thanks for clearing this up for me - sorry for thanking so late

Comment: Thanks for the link to the series of articles about programming a game in Erlang. Pure gold.

Comment: Helpful explanation but what about persistent state?  How would you build an application that maintains customer records?  And how does a functional program handle an enormous amount of data such an Internet search engine that you'd typically build with a distributed database?  And if the answer is somehow that the whole thing is kept in memory on a stack, then how do functional programs recover from a hardware failure?

Comment: @MichaelOsofsky, when interacting with databases and APIs, there is always an 'outside world' which has state to communicate with. In this case, you cannot go 100% functional. It is important to keep this 'unfunctional' code isolated and abstracted away so there is only one entry and one exit to the outside world. This way you can keep the rest of your code functional.

Comment: @Juliet, "Debugging is easy, all you need is a stack trace" how does it work in case of a tail recursion?

Comment: I would tweak this myself but I'm not sure I have it right, and I wouldn't want to step on any toes. When you say "The code above constructs two immutable lists, appends them together to make a new list, and appends the results." -- you mean *to the console*, right? The explicit object in the former clause makes the implicit object in the latter harder to determine (disambiguation of the method named "append" as opposed to stream insertion.) Re. large data: maybe consider a VM snapshot as immutable state; the snapshot is const wrt. the session but not wrt. merge/commit operations.

Comment: @vrnithinkumar This was already discussed (@reteptilian etc.) but I believe the idea is that in a single stack, you would have the base state, diffs, and a new state to be used as the base state for the tail call. At that point an assertion of some kind would reveal that the product is invalid, and the stack would contain the exact step from a valid state to an invalid one. Otherwise, yes, TCO would leave you with a stack trace only as useful as with mutable state - you're stuck with the necropsy. Disclaimer - I'm fairly new to FP & debugging (working on that brought me here.)

Comment: State does not go away entirely from the programs, but functional programs tend to push it out & make it as explicit as possible e.g. functions will now take state and actions and return state.
And then we also have fancy data structures under the hood for maintaining values.

Answer (score 85):

Short answer: you can't.

So what's the fuss about immutability then?

If you're well-versed in imperative language, then you know that "globals are bad". Why? Because they introduce (or have the potential to introduce) some very hard-to-untangle dependencies in your code. And dependencies are not good; you want your code to be *modular*. Parts of program not influence other parts as little as possible. And FP brings you to the holy grail of modularity: no side effects *at all*. You just have your f(x) = y. Put x in, get y out. No changes to x or anything else. FP makes you stop thinking about state, and start thinking in terms of values. All of your functions simply receive values and produce new values.

This has several advantages.

First off, no side-effects means simpler programs, easier to reason about. No worrying that introducing a new part of program is going to interfere and crash an existing, working part.

Second, this makes program trivially parallelizable (efficient parallelization is another matter).

Third, there are some possible performance advantages. Say you have a function:

```
double x = 2 * x
```

Now you put in a value of 3 in, and you get a value of 6 out. Every time. But you can do that in imperative as well, right? Yep. But the problem is that in imperative, you can do even *more*. I can do:

```
int y = 2;
int double(x){ return x * y; }
```

but I could also do

```
int y = 2;
int double(x){ return x * (y++); }
```

The imperative compiler doesn't know whether I'm going to have side effects or not, which makes it more difficult to optimize (i.e. double 2 needn't be 4 every time). The functional one knows I won't - hence, it can optimize every time it sees "double 2".

Now, even though creating new values every time seems incredibly wasteful for complex types of values in terms of computer memory, it doesn't have to be so. Because, if you have f(x) = y, and values x and y are "mostly the same" (e.g. trees which differ only in a few leafs) then x and y can share parts of memory - because neither of them will mutate.

So if this unmutable thing is so great, why did I answer that you can't do anything useful without mutable state. Well, without mutability, your entire program would be a giant f(x) = y function. And the same would go for all parts of your program: just functions, and functions in the "pure" sense at that. As I said, this means f(x) = y *every* time. So e.g. readFile("myFile.txt") would need to return the same string value every time. Not too useful.

Therefore, every FP provides *some* means of mutating state. "Pure" functional languages (e.g. Haskell) do this using somewhat scary concepts such as monads, while "impure" ones (e.g. ML) allow this directly.

And of course, functional languages come with a host of other goodies which make programming more efficient, such as first-class functions etc.

Comment: <<readFile("myFile.txt") would need to return the same string value every time. Not too useful.>> I am guessing it is useful as long as you hide the global, a filesystem.  If you consider it as a second parameter and let other processes return a new reference to the filesystem every time they modify it with filesystem2 = write(filesystem1, fd, pos, "string"), and let all processes exchange their reference to the filesystem, we could get a much cleaner picture of the operating system.

Comment: @eelghEEz, this is the same approach Datomic takes to databases.

Comment: +1 for the clear and concise comparison between paradigms. One suggestion is `int double(x){ return x * (++y); }` since the current one will still be 4, although still having an unadvertised side effect, whereas `++y` will return 6.

Comment: @eelghEEz I'm not sure of an alternative, really, is anyone else? To introduce information into a (pure-) FP context, you "take a measurement", e.g. "at timestamp X, the temperature is Y". If someone asks for the temperature, they may implicitly mean X=now, but they can't possibly be asking for the temperature as a universal function of time, right? FP deals with immutable state, and you have to create an immutable state - from internal *and* external sources - from a mutable one. Indices, timestamps, etc. are useful but orthogonal to mutability - like VCS are to version control itself.

Answer (score 31):

Note that saying functional programming does not have 'state' is a little misleading and might be the cause of the confusion. It definitely has no 'mutable state', but it can still have values that are manipulated; they just cannot be changed in-place (e.g. you have to create new values from the old values).

This is a gross over-simplification, but imagine you had an OO language, where all the properties on classes are set once only in the constructor, all methods are static functions. You could still perform pretty much any calculation by having methods take objects containing all the values they needs for their calculations and then returning new objects with the result (maybe a new instance of the same object even).

It may be 'hard' to translate existing code into this paradigm, but that is because it really requires a completely different way of thinking about code. As a side-effect though in most cases you get a lot of opportunity for parallelism for free.

**Addendum:** *(Regarding your edit of how to keep track of values that need to change)*
They would be stored in an immutable data structure of course...

This is not a suggested 'solution', but the easiest way to see that this will always work is that you could store these immutable values into a map (dictionary / hashtable) like structure, keyed by a 'variable name'.

Obviously in practical solutions you'd use a more sane approach, but this does show that worst-case if nothing else'd work you could 'simulate' mutable state with such a map that you carry around through your invocation tree.

Comment: OK, I changed the title. Your answer seems to lead to an even worse problem, though. If I have to recreate every object every time something in its state changes, I'll spend all my CPU time doing nothing but constructing objects. I'm thinking about game programming here, where you've got lots of things moving around on the screen (and off-screen) at once, that need to be able to interact with each other. The whole engine has a set framerate: everything you're going to do, you have to do in X number of miliseconds. Surely there's a better way than constantly recycling entire objects?

Comment: The beauty of it is that the imutability is on the language, not on the implementation. With a few tricks, you can have imutable state in the language while the implementation is in fact changing the state in place. See for instance Haskell's ST monad.

Comment: @Mason: The point being that the compiler can much better decide where it is (thread)safe to change the state in-place than you can.

Comment: I think for games you should avoid immutable for any parts where speed doesn't matter.  While an immutable language might optimize for you, nothing is going to be faster than modifying memory which CPUs are fast at doing.  And so if it turns out there are 10 or 20 places where you need imperative I think you should just avoid immutable altogether unless you can modularize it for very separated areas like game menus.  And game logic in particular could be a nice place to use immutable because I feel it's great for doing complex modelling of pure systems like business rules.

Comment: @LegendLength you're contradicting yourself.

Answer (score 24):

I think there's a slight misunderstanding. Pure functional programs have state. The difference is how that state is modeled. In pure functional programming, state is manipulated by functions that take some state and return the next state. Sequencing through states is then achieved by passing the state through a sequence of pure functions.

Even global mutable state can be modeled this way. In Haskell, for example, a program is a function from a World to a World. That is, you pass in *the entire universe*, and the program returns a new universe. In practise, though, you only need to pass in the parts of the universe in which your program is actually interested. And programs actually return *a sequence of actions* that serve as instructions for the operating environment in which the program runs.

You wanted to see this explained in terms of imperative programming. OK, let's look at some really simple imperative programming in a functional language.

Consider this code:

```
int x = 1;
int y = x + 1;
x = x + y;
return x;
```

Pretty bog-standard imperative code. Doesn't do anything interesting, but that's OK for illustration. I think you will agree that there's state involved here. The value of the x variable changes over time. Now, let's change the notation slightly by inventing a new syntax:

```
let x = 1 in
let y = x + 1 in
let z = x + y in z
```

Put parentheses to make it clearer what this means:

```
let x = 1 in (let y = x + 1 in (let z = x + y in (z)))
```

So you see, state is modeled by a sequence of pure expressions that bind the free variables of the following expressions.

You will find that this pattern can model any kind of state, even IO.

Comment: Is that kind of like a Monad?

Comment: Would you consider this:

A is declarative at level 1
B is declarative at level 2, it considers A to be imperative.
C is declarative at level 3, it considers B to be imperative.

As we increase the abstraction layer, it always considers languages lower on abstraction layer to be more imperative then itself.

Answer (score 15):

It's just different ways of doing the same thing.

Consider a simple example such as adding the numbers 3, 5, and 10. Imagine thinking about doing that by first changing the value of 3 by adding 5 to it, then adding 10 to that "3", then outputting the current value of "3" (18). This seems patently ridiculous, but it is in essence the way that state-based imperative programming is often done. Indeed, you can have many different "3"s that have the value 3, yet are different. All of this seems odd, because we have been so ingrained with the, quite enormously sensible, idea that the numbers are immutable.

Now think about adding 3, 5, and 10 when you take the values to be immutable. You add 3 and 5 to produce another value, 8, then you add 10 to that value to produce yet another value, 18.

These are equivalent ways to do the same thing. All of the necessary information exists in both methods, but in different forms. In one the information exists as state and in the rules for changing state. In the other the information exists in immutable data and functional definitions.

Answer (score 15):

Here's **how you write code without mutable state**: instead of putting changing state into mutable variables, you put it into the parameters of functions.  And instead of writing loops, you write recursive functions.  So for example this imperative code:

```
f_imperative(y) {
  local x;
  x := e;
  while p(x, y) do
    x := g(x, y)
  return h(x, y)
}
```

becomes this functional code (Scheme-like syntax):

```
(define (f-functional y) 
  (letrec (
     (f-helper (lambda (x y)
                  (if (p x y) 
                     (f-helper (g x y) y)
                     (h x y)))))
     (f-helper e y)))
```

or this Haskellish code

```
f_fun y = h x_final y
   where x_initial = e
         x_final   = loop x_initial
         loop x = if p x y then loop (g x y) else x
```

As to *why* functional programmers like to do this (which you did not ask), the more pieces of your program are stateless, **the more ways there are to put pieces together without having anything break**.  The power of the stateless paradigm lies not in statelessness (or purity) *per se*, but the ability it gives you to write powerful, *reusable* functions and combine them.

You can find a good tutorial with lots of examples in John Hughes's paper [Why Functional Programming Matters](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/Papers/whyfp.html).

Answer (score 12):

I'm late to the discussion, but I wanted to add a few points for people who are struggling with functional programming.

1. Functional languages maintain the exact same state updates as imperative languages but **they do it by passing the updated state to subsequent function calls**. Here is a very simple example of traveling down a number line. Your state is your current location.

First the imperative way (in pseudocode)

```
moveTo(dest, cur):
    while (cur != dest):
         if (cur < dest):
             cur += 1
         else:
             cur -= 1
    return cur
```

Now the functional way (in pseudocode). I'm leaning heavily on the ternary operator because I want people from imperative backgrounds to actually be able to read this code. So if you don't use the ternary operator much (I always avoided it in my imperative days) here is how it works.

```
predicate ? if-true-expression : if-false-expression
```

You can chain the ternary expression by putting a new ternary expression in place of the false-expression

```
predicate1 ? if-true1-expression :
predicate2 ? if-true2-expression :
else-expression
```

So with that in mind, here's the functional version.

```
moveTo(dest, cur):
    return (
        cur == dest ? return cur :
        cur < dest ? moveTo(dest, cur + 1) : 
        moveTo(dest, cur - 1)
    )
```

This is a trivial example. If this were moving people around in a game world, you'd have to introduce side effects like drawing the object's current position on the screen and introducing a bit of delay in each call based on how fast the object moves. But you still wouldn't need mutable state.

2. The lesson is that functional languages "mutate" state by calling the function with different parameters. Obviously this doesn't really mutate any variables, but that's how you get a similar effect. This means you'll have to get used to thinking recursively if you want to do functional programming.
3. Learning to think recursively is not hard, but it does take both practice and a toolkit. That small section in that "Learn Java" book where they used recursion to calculate factorial does not cut it. You need a toolkit of skills like making iterative processes out of recursion (this is why tail recursion is essential for functional language), continuations, invariants, etc. You wouldn't do OO programming without learning about access modifiers, interfaces etc. Same thing for functional programming.

My recommendation is to do the Little Schemer (note that I say "do" and not "read") and then do all the exercises in SICP. When you're done, you'll have a different brain than when you started.

Answer (score 9):

It is in fact quite easy to have something which looks like mutable state even in languages without mutable state.

Consider a function with type `s -> (a, s)`. Translating from Haskell syntax, it means a function which takes one parameter of type "`s`" and returns a pair of values, of types "`a`" and "`s`". If `s` is the type of our state, this function takes one state and returns a new state, and possibly a value (you can always return "unit" aka `()`, which is sort of equivalent to "`void`" in C/C++, as the "`a`" type). If you chain several calls of functions with types like this (getting the state returned from one function and passing it to the next), you have "mutable" state (in fact you are in each function creating a new state and abandoning the old one).

It might be easier to understand if you imagine the mutable state as the "space" where your program is executing, and then think of the time dimension. At instant t1, the "space" is in a certain condition (say for example some memory location has value 5). At a later instant t2, it is in a different condition (for example that memory location now has value 10). Each of these time "slices" is a state, and it is immutable (you cannot go back in time to change them). So, from this point of view, you went from the full spacetime with a time arrow (your mutable state) to a set of slices of spacetime (several immutable states), and your program is just treating each slice as a value and computing each of them as a function applied to the previous one.

OK, maybe that was not easier to understand :-)

It might seem inneficient to explicitly represent the whole program state as a value, which has to be created only to be discarded the next instant (just after a new one is created). For some algorithms it might be natural, but when it is not, there is another trick. Instead of a real state, you can use a fake state which is nothing more than a marker (let's call the type of this fake state `State#`). This fake state exists from the point of view of the language, and is passed like any other value, but the compiler completely omits it when generating the machine code. It only serves to mark the sequence of execution.

As an example, suppose the compiler gives us the following functions:

```
readRef :: Ref a -> State# -> (a, State#)
writeRef :: Ref a -> a -> State# -> (a, State#)
```

Translating from these Haskell-like declarations, `readRef` receives something which resembles a pointer or a handle to a value of type "`a`", and the fake state, and returns the value of type "`a`" pointed to by the first parameter and a new fake state. `writeRef` is similar, but changes the value pointed to instead.

If you call `readRef` and then pass it the fake state returned by `writeRef` (perhaps with other calls to unrelated functions in the middle; these state values create a "chain" of function calls), it will return the value written. You can call `writeRef` again with the same pointer/handle and it will write to the same memory location — but, since conceptually it is returning a new (fake) state, the (fake) state is still imutable (a new one has been "created"). The compiler will call the functions in the order it would have to call them if there was a real state variable which had to be computed, but the only state which there is is the full (mutable) state of the real hardware.

(Those who know Haskell will notice I simplified things a lot and ommited several important details. For those who want to see more details, take a look at `Control.Monad.State` from the `mtl`, and at the `ST s` and `IO` (aka `ST RealWorld`) monads.)

You might wonder why doing it in such a roundabout way (instead of simply having mutable state in the language). The real advantage is that you have [reified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_(computer_science)) your program's state. What before was implicit (your program state was global, allowing for things like [action at a distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_at_a_distance_(computer_science))) is now explicit. Functions which do not receive and return the state cannot modify it or be influenced by it; they are "pure". Even better, you can have separate state threads, and with a bit of type magic, they can be used to embed an imperative computation within a pure one, without making it impure (the `ST` monad in Haskell is the one normally used for this trick; the `State#` I mentioned above is in fact GHC's `State# s`, used by its implementation of the `ST` and `IO` monads).

Answer (score 7):

Functional programming *avoids* state and *emphasizes* functionality.  There's never any such thing as no state, though the state might actually be something that's immutable or baked into the architecture of what you're working with.  Consider the difference between a static web server that just loads up files off the filesystem versus a program that implements a Rubik's cube.  The former is going to be implemented in terms of functions designed to turn a request into a file path request into a response from the contents of that file.  Virtually no state is needed beyond a tiny bit of configuration (the filesystem 'state' is really outside the scope of the program.  The program works the same way regardless of what state the files are in).  In the latter though, you need to model the cube and your program implementation of how operations on that cube change its state.

Comment: When I was more anti-functional I wondered how it could be good when something like a hard drive is mutable.  My c# classes all had mutable state and could very logically simulate a hard drive or any other device.  Whereas with functional there was a mismatch between the models and the actual machines they were modelling.  After delving further into functional I've come to realize the benefits you get are able to outweigh that issue a fair bit.  And if it were physically possible to invent a hard drive that made a copy of itself it would actually be useful (like journalling already does).

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the great answers others are giving, think about the classes `Integer` and `String` in Java.  Instances of these classes are immutable, but that doesn't make the classes useless just because their instances cannot be changed.  The immutability gives you some safety.  You know if you use a String or Integer instance as the key to a `Map`, the key cannot be changed.  Compare this to the `Date` class in Java:

```
Date date = new Date();
mymap.put(date, date.toString());
// Some time later:
date.setTime(new Date().getTime());
```

You have silently changed a key in your map!  Working with immutable objects, such as in Functional Programming, is a lot cleaner.  It's easier to reason about what side effects occur -- none!  This means it's easier for the programmer, and also easier for the optimizer.

Comment: I understand that, but it doesn't answer my question.  Keeping in mind that a computer program is a model of some real-world event or process, if you can't change your values, then how do you model something that changes?

Comment: Well, you can certainly do useful things with the Integer and String classes.  It's not like their immutability means you cannot have mutable state.

Comment: @Mason Wheeler - By understanding that a thing and it's state are two different "things". What pacman is doesn't change from time A to time B. Where pacman is does change. When you move from time A to time B, you get a new combination of pacman + state... which is the same pacman, different state. Not changed state... different state.

Answer (score 5):

Using some creativity and pattern matching, stateless games have been created:

- [CSSPlay: Maze Game](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/amazing.html)
- [CSSPlay: Maze Game 2](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/maze2.html)
- [CSSPlay: Tic-Tac-Toe](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/tictactoe.html)
- [Pure CSS Tic-Tac-Toe](http://lea.verou.me/2011/06/pure-css-tic-tac-toe/)
- [CSSPlay: Pong](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/cssplay-pong2.html)
- [CSSPlay: Ping-Pong](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/cssplay-ping-pong.html)
- [CSSPlay: Cops and Robbers](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/tilt)
- [CSSPlay: Whack-a-Rat](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/cssplay-whack-a-rat.html)
- [CSS3 Pong: Insane Things to do with CSS](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-pong-insane-things-to-do-with-css/)

as well as rolling demos:

- [CSSPlay: Random Heroes](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/cssplay-random-heroes.html)
- [Animated Analog SVG Clock](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4d/Animated_analog_SVG_clock.svg)
- [Animated SVG Pendulum](http://tecfa.unige.ch/guides/svg/ex/smil-dom/pendula.svg)
- [Animated SVG Racers](http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/newstuff/SMIL7g.svg)
- [CSS3: Making Snow](http://standardista.com/snow/#slide1)

and visualizations:

- [XSLT Mandlebrot](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/jutut/xslt-mandelbrot/mandelbrot.xml)

Answer (score 4):

For highly interactive applications such as games, **Functional Reactive Programming** is your friend: if you can formulate the properties of your game's world as **time-varying values** (and/or event streams), you are ready! These formulae will be sometimes even more natural and intent-revealing than mutating a state, e.g. for a moving ball, you can directly use the well-known law **x = v * t**. And what's better, the game's rules written such way **compose** better than object-oriented abstractions. For example, in this case, the ball's speed can be also a time-varying value, which depends on the event stream consisting of the ball's collisions. For more concrete design considerations, see [Making Games in Elm](http://elm-lang.org/blog/games-in-elm/part-0/Making-Pong.html).

Answer (score 3):

That's the way FORTRAN would work without COMMON blocks: You'd write methods that had the values you passed in and local variables. That's it.

Object oriented programming brought us state and behavior together, but it was a new idea when I first encountered it from C++ back in 1994.

Geez, I was a functional programmer when I was a mechanical engineer and I didn't know it!

Comment: I'd disagree that this is something you can pin on OO.  Languages before OO encouraged coupling state and algorithms.  OO just provided a better way to manage it.

Comment: "Encouraged" - perhaps.  OO make it an explicit part of the language.  You can do encapsulation and information hiding in C, but I'd say that OO languages make it a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

Bear in mind:  functional languages are Turing complete.  Therefore, any useful task you would perform in an imperitive language can be done in a functional language.  At the end of the day though, I think there's something to be said of a hybrid approach.  Languages like F# and Clojure (and I'm sure others) encourage stateless design, but allow for mutability when necessary.

Comment: Just because two languages are Turing complete does not mean they can perform the same tasks. What it means is they can perform the same computation. Brainfuck is Turing complete, but I'm fairly certain it can't communicate over a TCP stack.

Comment: Sure it can.  Given the same access to hardware as say C, it can.  That doesn't mean that it would be practical, but the possibility is there.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a pure functional language that is useful. There will always be a level of mutability that you have to deal with, IO is one example.

Think of functional languages as just another tool that you use. Its good for certain things, but not others. The game example you gave might not be the best way to use a functional language, at least the screen will have a mutable state that you can't do anything about with FP. The way you think of problem and the type of problems you solve with FP will be different from ones you are used to with imperative programming.

Answer (score 1):

By using lots of recursion.

[Tic Tac Toe in F# (A functional language.)](http://www.siafoo.net/snippet/246)

Comment: Of course, tail-recursion can be implemented very efficiently, since compilers can convert it into a loop.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: You can do any computation without mutable state, but when it comes time to actually tell the computer what to do, since the computer only works with mutable state, you need to mutate something at some point.

There are a lot of answers that correctly say that you cannot do anything useful without mutable state, and I wanted to back that up with some simple (counter)examples, as well as a general intuition.

If you see any piece of code deemed "purely functional" and it does something like this (not a real language):

```hs
printUpToTen = map println [1..10]
```

this is not purely functional. There is a hidden state (that of `stdout`) that is being not only mutated but implicitly passed in. Code that looks like this (again not a real language):

```hs
printUpToTen = map println stdout [1..10]
```

is also not pure: even if we explicitly pass in state (`stdout`), it is still being implicitly mutated.

Now for some intuition: mutable state is necessary because the core building block of what affects our computer is mutable state, that building block being memory. We cannot compel the computer to do anything without manipulating this memory somehow, even if our computational model can indeed compute anything without the concept of "memory".

Think of something like an old GameBoy Advance: in order to display something to the screen, you must modify the memory (there are certain addresses that are read many times a second that determine whats being put on the screen). Your computational model (pure functional programming) may not need state to operate, you may even be able to implement you model using an imperative, state manipulation model (like assembly) that abstracts the state manipulation, but at the end of the day, somewhere in you code you have to modify those addresses in memory for the device to actually display anything.

This is where imperative models have a natural advantage: since they are always manipulating state, you can very easily translate that over to actually modifying memory. Here is an example rendering loop:

```c
while (1) {
   render(graphics_state);
}
```

If you were to unroll the loop, it looks like this:

```c
render(graphics_state); // modified the memory
render(graphics_state); // modified the memory
render(graphics_state); // modified the memory
...
```

But in a pure functional language, you might get something like this:

```hs
render_forever state = render_forever newState
    where newState = render state
```

Unrolled (or flattened to be precise) can be visualized like this:

```
render(render(render(render(...state) // when is the memory actually changing??

// or if you want to expand it the other direction
...der(render(render(render(render(render(state) // no mutation
```

As you can see we are calling a function over and over again on the state, which is changing, but we never mutate memory: we immediately pass it to the next function call. Even if our implementation is actually modifying something that represents the state (in place even!) under the hood, it's not in the right place. At some point we need to pause and modify the correct address in memory, which involves a mutation.

Answer (score 0):

Let's answer the more general question:

> How can you do anything useful without state?

## You don't.

> *In seeking an alternative to conventional language
> we must first recognize that a system cannot be history
> sensitive (permit execution of one program to affect the
> behavior of a subsequent one) unless the system has
> some kind of state (which the first program can change
> and the second can access). **Thus a history-sensitive
> model of a computing system must have a state-transition
> semantics**, at least in this weak sense.*
>
> [John Backus](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ecrary/819-f09/Backus78.pdf).

<sup>(emphasis by me.)</sup>

What is important is Backus's subsequent observation:

> *But this does not
> mean that every computation must depend heavily on
> complex state [...]*

Functional languages like [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org) or [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl/Clean) allow you to easily put this observation into practice: the majority of definitions would be plain ol' functions, just like the ones you saw in your mathematics education. That leaves a small "motley crew" to then deal with all that annoying external state in order to e.g:

- interact with a user,
- communicate with a remote service,
- handle simulating using random sampling,
- print out [an SVG file](https://futureofcoding.org/essays/dctp.html) (e.g. as a poster),
- make scheduled backups,

...where both languages separate the plain from the motley by using types.

---

Sometimes, the algorithm you're trying to implement works best if it's implemented using private, local mutable state. In such circumstances, you can use a Haskell extension to do just that **without** the whole program going "motley on the inside" - see [State in Haskell](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.52.3656&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by John Launchbury and Simon Peyton Jones for the details.

Answer (score 0):

Question: what is `(int i = 0; i < 42; ++i){}`

Answer: a table(and to my horror `bash` does it that way)

Conclusion: all modern/procedural programming is looking up databases.

Answer (score -2):

JavaScript provides very clear examples of the different ways of approaching mutable or immutable state\values within its core because the ECMAScript specifications were not able to settle on a universal standard so one must continue to memorize or doublecheck which functions create a new object that they return or modify the original object passed to it. If your entire language is immutable then you know you are always getting a new (copied & possibly modified) result and never have to worry about accidentally modifying the variable before passing it into a function.

Do you know which returns a new object and which changes the original of the following examples?

```
Array.prototype.push()
String.prototype.slice()
Array.prototype.splice()
String.prototype.trim()
```

Comment: Hi @Supamic, I've downvoted you because you are quizzing the OP rather than giving them a concrete answer. Also, "JavaScript provides very clear examples" doesn't make much sense. JavaScript itself provides no examples of anything.

Answer (score -3):

This is very simple.  You can use as many variables as you want in functional programming...but only if they're **local** variables (contained inside functions).  So just wrap your code in functions, pass values back and forth among those functions (as passed parameters and returned values)...and that's all there is to it!

Here's an example:

```
function ReadDataFromKeyboard() {
    $input_values = $_POST[];
    return $input_values;
}
function ProcessInformation($input_values) {
    if ($input_values['a'] > 10)
        return ($input_values['a'] + $input_values['b'] + 3);
    else if ($input_values['a'] > 5)
        return ($input_values['b'] * 3);
    else
        return ($input_values['b'] - $input_values['a'] - 7);
}
function DisplayToPage($data) {
    print "Based your input, the answer is: ";
    print $data;
    print "\n";
}

/* begin: */
DisplayToPage (
    ProcessInformation (
        GetDataFromKeyboard()
    )
);
```

Comment: John, what language is this?