# Functional Programming Way: How to avoid overhead of copy object in Java?

Tags: java, functional-programming

I'm a novice user of functional programming. I might have a misconception about functional programming (FP) but, I think a pure FP language does not allow mutable object.

I have two questions. One is somehow theoretical and the other one is about a concrete Java code.

**Question 1**
How does a pure FP language avoid performance overhead of copying object?

```
var x = getMassiveObject()
var y = f(x)
```

I think `x` must be copied in `f` because `x` is immutable and nobody can not touch the memory space of `x`. If `x` is huge, copying process seems to take a lot of time.

But, I did not read any discussion about this point, so I believe there is not this kind of overhead in FP language.

So, **my first question is** How does FP language avoid the overhead of copying immutable huge object?

**Question2**
I'd like to build Java program with FP way to avoid side-effect. **My second question** is how can I rewrite below code to eliminate a overhead of copy?

```
public void main(){
  MassiveClass m = new MassiveClass();
  MassiveClass n = convert(m);
}

public MassiveClass convert(MassiveClass arg){
  MassiveClass arg2 = deepCopy(arg); // copy arg because arg should not be modified
  arg2.var = 100;
  return arg2
}
```

Comment: If you want to change something, but don't want to modify the original, then how would you possibly not copy it? At best, you don't need a deep copy if you're only changing one field.

Comment: One option is to use wrappers. I am not saying that this is done, but it is certainly possible to have WrapperClass extends MassiveClass and implement the methods of MassiveClass by delegation into a contained, unmodified massive.

Comment: shallow copy is enough

Comment: @immibis thanks. You means FP language always suffers from overhead of copy when a modified instance is needed?

Comment: This question has a nice answer about functional programming and mutability. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020653/how-can-you-do-anything-useful-without-mutable-state and you may also be interested in Functional Java at http://www.functionaljava.org/ and take a look at some of the materials created by Neal Ford such as the series of articles on IBM Developer Works library https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-ft1/

Answer (score 1):

**First question:** `x` is not copied. It's passed to function `f`. Immutability means `x` will remain the same and its state will not change after construction and until the end of object's lifecycle.

**Second question:** In order an object to be immutable in Java, all of its fields should be immutable. If you put `List` as a field in `MassiveClass`, it's not immutable anymore. You have to do defensive copying, as already you did.

Comment: Thanks, but I believe x is (at least implicitly) copied before obtaining updated object in f. This is because of the same reason that is mentioned by @immibis in the comment section.

Comment: Well, what you believe might not be true. Address of `x`  is copied, not `x` itself. When you call `f(m)` where m is `MassiveObject` in Java, address of `m` is copied, not `m` itself. That's the whole point of immutability. The class must be immutable because the object is passed around in the program. It should not allow any mutations after construction.

Comment: thanks, but still I think my assumption is right. In Java, just a reference is passed. That's why I believe copying the argument is necessary before getting the updated object and it leads the overhead. However, in FP, that's kind of overhead doesn't seems to be a problem. So, my question is how the overhead is avoided inFP, and how can I realize that in Java.

Comment: @rkjt50r983 I believe you're not understanding each other because you forgot, in your original question #1, to say what `f()` *does* and *returns*. Does it do something like your `convert()` method in question #2?

Comment: @rkjt50r983 You're wrong. In pure FP, data are immutable, and thus are not updated. Hence, no need to copy them.