# What is scikit-learn FunctionTransformer used for?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

From the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer.html) I already read that:

> *A FunctionTransformer forwards its X (and optionally y) arguments to a user-defined function or function object and returns the result of
> this function. This is useful for stateless transformations such as
> taking the log of frequencies, doing custom scaling, etc.*

However, I don't understand what use this function has. Could anybody explain the purpose of this function?

Comment: One use-case i could think of: add some *stateless transformation* like scaling to a non-simple pipeline (e.g. dimension-reduction -> classifier within cross-validation). This abstract function should deliver the interface needed for this pipeline (fit, transform and co.) without any need to write this for yourself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In addition to simply wrapping a given user-defined function, the [FunctionTransformer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer) provides some standard methods of other sklearn estimators (e.g., `fit` and `transform`). The benefit of this is that you can introduce arbitrary, stateless transforms into an sklearn [Pipeline](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/pipeline.html), which combines multiple processing stages. This makes executing a processing pipeline easier because you can simply pass your data (`X`) to the `fit` and `transform` methods of the `Pipeline` object without having to explicitly apply each stage of the pipeline individually.

Here is an example copied directly from the sklearn documentation (located [here](https://scikit-learn.org/0.23/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_function_transformer.html)):

```
def all_but_first_column(X):
    return X[:, 1:]
```

```
def drop_first_component(X, y):
    """
    Create a pipeline with PCA and the column selector and use it to
    transform the dataset.
    """
    pipeline = make_pipeline(
        PCA(), FunctionTransformer(all_but_first_column),
    )
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
    pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
    return pipeline.transform(X_test), y_test
```

Note that the first principal component wasn't explicitly removed from the data. The pipeline automatically chains the transformations together when `pipeline.transform` is called.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Could you provide an example?.

Comment: @ml_student See the example I added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: The code example has been relocated or removed. Here's a versioned link to [Using FunctionTransformer to select columns](https://scikit-learn.org/0.23/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_function_transformer.html).

Comment: Beware, you need to define `inverse_transform`

Answer (score 4):

#### *Custom Function Use Case*

Let's say you have image arrays with a known value range between `0-255` that you want to scale down between `0-1`, but you don't want to use `StandardScaler` because not all images would have values of 0 and 255 in them. In simpler terms. No one scored a 100% on the test, but you still want to scale between 0-100.

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer
import numpy as np


data = np.array([[100, 2], [240, 80], [139, 10], [10, 150]])


def div255(X): return X/255 #encode
def mult255(X): return X*255 #decode
scaler = FunctionTransformer(div255, inverse_func=mult255)


# --- encode ---
mutated = scaler.fit_transform(data)
"""
array([[0.39215686, 0.00784314],
       [0.94117647, 0.31372549],
       [0.54509804, 0.03921569],
       [0.03921569, 0.58823529]])
"""

# --- decode ---
scaler.inverse_transform(mutated)
"""
array([[100.,   2.],
       [240.,  80.],
       [139.,  10.],
       [ 10., 150.]])
"""
```

#### *Pro Tip*

Make sure you define these custom functions in a place where they can be referenced by the rest of your program (e.g. *helper functions*). Especially for when it comes time to `inverse_transform` your predictions and/or encode new samples!

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_function_transformer.html#example-preprocessing-plot-function-transformer-py) is a nice example. It really is what it says: given X input, it applies your function to X and returns the result. The most important part of it is its statelessness. [Here](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/stateless) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329618/stateless-vs-stateful-i-could-use-some-concrete-information) you can find what statelessness is and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844536/advantages-of-stateless-programming) you can read a discussion about its advantages.

Comment: Please add examples to your answers. The link is now broken.

Comment: I wrote this 5 years ago. I have no idea what was under that link.

Answer (score -1):

```
X =  [[5,6,7],
      [8,9,10],
      [1,2,3]]    

def exampleFunctionTransformer(X):
        return  X**2

    def exampleofFunctionTransfor():
        fx = FunctionTransformer(exampleFunctionTransformer)
        Y1= fx.transform(X)
        print(Y1)
        return Y1

    Z = exampleofFunctionTransfor()

    print(Z)


o/p 

    [[ 25  36  49]
     [ 64  81 100]
     [  1   4   9]]
```

refer this : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer