# setState doens't cause re-render of new screen in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, state

I got a `List`, called `savedListsList`, that contains a list of `Objects`. When the app starts this list is empty. When the users clicks on a `PopupMenuItem` (depicted in the `case 0:` case), data is loaded from an internal database and after that, a new screen shows up where the data is shown (basically a `StatelessWidget` that contains a `ListView.builder` with a certain amount of rows).

Every row consists of a `GestureDetector` that listens for left and right swipes.
On every of these swipes `updateSaveListItem` is called. According to the `beingEdited` attribute the appearance of the row inside the before mentioned `ListView.builder` is changed.

I know that the swipes trigger the attribute to change accordingly, since I printed that out.

Unfortunately the change in `updateSavedListItem` doesn't cause a re-render of the current screen. When I hot-reload the app the change of `beingEdited` is reflected.

I'm pretty sure that I can get this to work, when I turn the 
widget that surrounds the `ListView.builder` into a `StatefulWidget`. 
But my question is: can I trigger a re-render of the current page with the architecture I described? Since I want to keep as much of my `state` management as I can inside my `_MainPage` `class`.

```
class _MainPage extends State<MainPage> {
List<SavedListObj> savedListsList = List();

  @override
  void initState() {
   savedListsList = List();
  }

  void updateSavedListItem(int id, String action, String newName) {
   setState(() {
    switch (action) {
     case 'beingEditedStart':
       savedListsList[id].beingEdited = true;
      break;
     case 'beingEditedEnd':
       savedListsList[id].beingEdited = false;
      break;
     case 'delete':
      break;
     case 'edit':
      break;
    }
   });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

   return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
    actions: <Widget>[
      PopupMenuButton(
        onSelected: (value) {
          switch (value) {
            case 0:
             DB db = DB();
              db.getListNames().then((queryResult) {
                savedListsList.clear();
                setState(() {
                  savedListsList.addAll(queryResult);
                });

                Navigator.push(
                 context,
                 MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => SavedListsPage(
                            savedListsList,
                            updateSavedListItem,
                           ),
                       ),
                  );
             break;
          }
        },
       ),
      ],
     ),
    );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot do that! you have to use Stateful widget when you have to update the state of your app. For futher reference you can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47501710/what-is-the-relation-between-stateful-and-stateless-widgets-in-flutter).