# How stateful widget works in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I was learning flutter and came across stateful widget. Frankly, when I first faced stateful widget, that was quite confusing for me. So, here is the code:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
 }
```

The question is Is it true that when we, say, call setState in `_MyHomePageState` build function is called and THEN createState() is called which then calls `_MyHomePageState()`? So, again every time setState() is called, the following things will happen build() is invoked then createState() which then calls `_MyHomePageState()`.Is that true?

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47501710/what-is-the-relation-between-stateful-and-stateless-widgets-in-flutter ?

Comment: No, it's not true ! `createState()` method is called once. The `setState()` method will only call the `build` method of the `State<MyHomePage>` class

Comment: @FPerroch, ok but how does MyHomePage know that _MyHomePageState has rebuilt has new state?

Comment: It doesn't knows. It only creates the `State` class