# Flutter - Text which changes dynamically Stateless or Stateful?

Tags: flutter, flutter-state

Suppose I have a text widget that changes dynamically (ie the text changes based on conditions, button clicks etc). So now is the Text stateless or Stateful?

As per definition "A stateless widget never changes. Icon, IconButton, and Text are examples of stateless widgets. Stateless widgets subclass StatelessWidget."

Text is a Stateless widget but the content of text is changing so why is it not stateful?

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47502202/5235984) will help you understand stateless vs stateful.

Comment: It is stateful. If you want it to become stateless you have to add the keyword "const" (without the quotation marks) to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text is stateless because Text itself never does not change its content on its own, which matches the definition you mentioned.

In the case you mentioned, it will be another widget that's going to change the content of the Text widget.