# stateless widget vs stateful widget performance

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

What would happen if we converted a stateless widget to a stateful widget? Is there any performance issue?

Comment: Have you looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47501710/what-is-the-relation-between-stateful-and-stateless-widgets-in-flutter)

Comment: No noticeable performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

If your widget remains static then you can use stateless widget otherwise you can use stateful widgets.

there is no performance issues, in my opinion