# Statelesswidget, statefulwidget with firebase real time database

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

The difference between statelesswidget and statefulwidget? Also how do I connect real database on firebase using statelesswidget with flutter on adroid

Comment: Stateless widget does not have setState which allows it repaint.
https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/interactive#stateful-stateless
I do not think you use statelesswidget for anything with state like connecting to a database

Comment: Thank you, the link you provided is on point

Comment: duplicate
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47501710/what-is-the-relation-between-stateful-and-stateless-widgets-in-flutter

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329618/stateless-vs-stateful-i-could-use-some-concrete-information/25582424#25582424