# Exclamation mark in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Given the following facts and predicates:

```
sound(time1).
sound(time2).
sun(time3).
relax(X):-sound(X),!,sun(X).
relax(_):-sun(_).
```

When executing `relax(S).` I'd expect to get `S=time1` due to the `!`, that says (correct me if I'm wrong), that if 'X' is satisfied , then stop the backtracking.

Here is the trace:

```
3 ?- trace.
true.

[trace] 3 ?- relax(S).
   Call: (6) relax(_G1831) ? creep
   Call: (7) sound(_G1831) ? creep
   Exit: (7) sound(time1) ? creep
   Call: (7) sun(time1) ? creep
   Fail: (7) sun(time1) ? creep
   Fail: (6) relax(_G1831) ? creep
false.
```

So why does Prolog also checks `sun(time1)`, even though that it met the exclamation mark after being satisfied by `sound(X)` (because `sound(time1)` is a fact).

Comment: This has nothing to do with functional programming and isn't appropriate for the programming-languages tag either... don't add tags just because you feel like it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `!` sign prevents backtracking of the clauses to the right of it to the left, it's like a one-way gate so that it won't backtrack beyond the cut.

When `sound(time1)` is true, the next clause `sun(time1)` will be evaluated, and only then prolog will find that `sun(time1)` is `false` (by searching the knowledge base, it doesn't actually *know* that it's a fact).

Then, because of the cut, prolog won't try values `time2` and `time3` in the first clause.

**More about cut:**

Prolog evaluates the clauses of a predicate left to right. It binds a value to a variable in the leftmost clause. If the clause is `true`, it moves to the next one. If it's `false`, prolog tries other values as well.

If any of the clauses cannot be satisfied by any value, it would be `false`, and so will be the whole predicate (because the clauses are joined by AND).

The whole thing works as a depth-first traversal of a tree, where the clauses are the nodes and the edges represent different values of its variable. If the traversal finds a clause to be `false`, it would return to its preceding clause and try a different value.

Here comes the cut. If you put a cut (`!`) between two clauses, it would mean that if the clause *after* a cut becomes `false`, trying new values will go on ONLY IF the evaluation runs AFTER the cut. It means the values of the variables used before the cut are *locked*, and they cannot be changed when the evaluation crosses the cut.

Comment: So what you're saying is that there is no difference between `relax(X):-sound(X),!,sun(X).` and `relax(X):-sound(X),sun(X),!.`  ? prolog would try only the current 'X' and then fail ... ?

Comment: @ron Of course there is a difference between the two, which is the location of the cut. The first version might give you the answer multiple times if `sun(X)` can be solved more than once - e.g. if you add `sun(time1).` and `sun(X) :- sound(X).` to your predicates and then ask for `relax(S)`. The second version will always result in one (or no) answer. You are correct though that it won't make a difference for your current set of predicates.

Comment: @l4mpi:OK ,so that's the weird part : why does prolog check beyond the `!` in `relax(X):-sound(X),!,sun(X).` ? If prolog found that `relax(time1)` is a fact , won't the `!` tell it not to check anything else , and in addition not to check also `sun(time1)` ?

Comment: @ron you misunderstood what the cut does. It does not stop evaluation, it just means that all choice points accumulated until `!` are discarded. When `sound(X)` is reached, possible soulutions are `time1` and `time2`. The prolog interpreter chooses the first one (`time1`) and creates a choice point it can backtrack to if the rest of the clause fails, so it can re-evaluate with `time2`. The `!` does nothing except discarding this choice point. Prolog now evaluates the rest of the predicate, but can't backtrack before the `!` and test with `time2` anymore.

Comment: @ron Prolog can __check__ beyond a cut (left to right), but cannot __backtrack__ beyond a cut (right to left) - that's why a cut is like a one-way gate.

Answer (score 41):

To clarify this even more, if somebody still struggles how exclamation operator works (*like i did*), here is an example:

```
sound(time3).
sound(time1).
sun(time1).
relax(X):-sound(X),!,sun(X).
```

For this certain example, if you ask Prolog for `?-relax(S).` this results into **false**. We can describe Prolog working like this:

1. Prolog searches for asked predicate (*relax(SOMEVARIABLE unifiable
   with S))* in our example).
2. Prolog finds predicate relax(X). Variables
   X and S are now bound.
3. Prolog starts to evaluate clauses:

   - **sound(X)**

     - Prolog searches the file for fact which
       satisfies sound(X).
     - it finds the fact **sound(time3).** and unifies it with our variables X=S=time3.
   - **!**

     - Prolog continues to next clausule which is operator ! so he will not backtrack back behind this operator.
   - **sun(X)**

     - Prolog searches the file for the fact which satisfies sun(X). X is already bound so it searches for **sun(time3)** which does not
       exists.
4. **Conclusion**

   - at this point, if there was no ! operator Prolog would return (*backtrack*) to sound(X) and it would reassign variable X=S as X=S=time1. Which would eventually result into **true** since fact *sun(time1)* exists.
   - Prolog returns false because he could not match relax(S) for any rule.

In opposition like I said in 4. without ! operator it results into **success**.

```
sound(time3).
sound(time1).
sun(time1).
relax(X):-sound(X),sun(X).
```

Feel free to correct me if I am wrong at some point.

Comment: I found this explanation to be much clearer than the accepted answer, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

It will still try to satisfy the rest of the rule, it just won't backtrace to before the exclamation mark. That is, if `sun(X)` fails, it won't backtrace and try to match a *different* object to `sound(X)`, but fail to match that rule entirely.