# Recursion in Lisp and making my own length function

Tags: function, lisp, control-flow

I am trying to make my own length/2 function(which allows you to find the length of a list) in lisp and am having an issue.

If I were to program this in java I would create a global index variable

```
that = 0
```

Then in the method I would do

```
if(list.equal(null))
{
    return index;
}
else
{
    index++;
    return functioname(tail of list) ;
}.
```

Obviously this is not actual java syntax but I am just trying to relay the logic I want to apply in lisp.

My main issue is that ifs in lisp only allow you to do

```
if test expression
    then do something
else
    do something else
```

while I am trying to do

```
if test expression
    then do something
else
    do 2x something
```

Is there a way I can accomplish this in lisp or is there a better way to go about this problem?

Comment: Could you explain `length/2 function`?

Comment: Ah sorry about that. I have made the necessary edit to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it recursively:

```
len(list):
    if list is null
        return 0
    else
        remove first_item from list
        return 1 + len(list)


(define (length items)
  (if (null? items)
      0
      (+ 1
         (length (cdr items)))))


(length (list 1 2 3))
```

> 3

Or use `set!`:

```
(define count 0)

(define (length items)
  (when (not (null? items))
    (set! count (+ count 1))
    (length (cdr items))))

(length (list 1 2 3 4 5))

count
```

> 5

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense, but there is no way to use a global index variable to do the same thing?(ie instead of adding 1, increment the index)

Comment: @JmanxC I guess you want to do: change `count` variable (+1) while going through a list. But lisp variable is immutable by default.

Comment: Yes exactly or (incr index) before the recursive call.  Sorry I am not sure what you mean by immutable, what does (incr index) do if the variable cannot be altered?

Comment: @JmanxC about immutability: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844536/advantages-of-stateless-programming

Comment: Perfect the second example does exactly what I wanted. I will also have to read a bit more on immutability with regards to functional programming. From what I am getting, in functional programming variable immutability means that any change of state in a program(in this example a recursive call) does not change the state of a variable? Is this a correct understanding? If not I'll probably have to read more.

Comment: @JmanxC In fact many modern Lisp implementation does enable `mutability` though functional programming typically avoids using mutable state.

Comment: Ah ok. One last problem haha I tried to apply the following and I get a result of nil. Not sure why.

Comment: (defun length2(myList)
                 (when (not (equal nil myList) )
                 (defparameter index (+ index 1) )
                 (length2 (cdr myList) ) ) )

Comment: Sorry for everything being on one line,not sure how to edit comments

Comment: I also tried setf instead of defparameter, with same results. Your "set!" is not a defined function in common lisp.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking :P. I posted the code in my comment above but I wasn't sure how to space out different lines of text in comments.  I applied the code in common lisp and it returned nil instead of the length of the list.

Comment: modify your code from  `(defun length2 (myList) implementation)` to `(defun (length2 myList) implementation)`

Comment: Gives the follow error : Error: (LENGTH2 MYLIST) is neither of type SYMBOL nor a list of the form (SETF SYMBOL).

Comment: @JmanxC I was wrong about the syntax. Did your initialize `index`?

Comment: Yes I defined it before creating the function

Comment: ie: (setf index 0)

Answer (score 0):

Scheme has the special operator `begin` (the Common Lisp equivalent is `progn`) that lets you group expressions which are executed in sequence, and returns the last one.

```
(if (null? items)
    0
    (begin (set! index (+ 1 index))
           (my-length (cdr items))
           index))
```

If the `if` expression returns `nil` under the false condition, then you can also use `when` (as in Rahn's answer) which is a bit more compact.

That said, having a global variable, or any variable at all, whose value gets changed (which is the purpose of a variable) is not the Lisp/recursive way of doing things. (Global variables are not a good thing in any language.) Rahn's first example is the only way any experienced Lisp programmer would do it.

In my example above, the `(set! index (+ 1 index))` and `index))` lines, and the global variable `index` are completely unnecessary if you add the 1 to the `(my-length (cdr items))`. If the list is empty, the length is zero; otherwise, the length is 1 + the length of the tail of the list.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will just go about it not using global variables then and do it the first way.